# Aggregating Data from different lines in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, calendar, pivot

I've got a very simple table that I need to create a view from. The table itself has different rooms, and the start/end time each room is in use (has a reservation).

```
Date             Start_Time               End_Time              Room

2019-06-08       08:00                    09:00                 101
2019-06-08       12:00                    14:00                 101
2019-06-08       18:30                    20:00                 101
2019-06-08       10:00                    13:30                 201
2019-06-08       14:00                    15:00                 201
2019-06-08       08:00                    09:00                 308
2019-06-08       09:30                    12:15                 308
2019-06-08       16:00                    17:00                 308
2019-06-08       17:30                    18:00                 308
```

Assume that there are more dates, rooms, and times of course. Time is actually stored as datetime, but I'm simplifying it here.

What I'm trying to do is create a View where we can see the times each room is available between reservations, by day. This means that the End Time for a room reservation becomes the Start Time that a room is available, and the Start Time of the **next** room reservation is the End Time that the room is available.

Result would look like this.

```
Date             Start_Time               End_Time              Room

2019-06-08       00:00                    08:00                 101
2019-06-08       09:00                    12:00                 101
2019-06-08       14:00                    18:30                 101
2019-06-08       20:00                    23:59                 101
2019-06-08       00:00                    10:00                 201
2019-06-08       13:30                    14:00                 201
2019-06-08       15:00                    23:59                 201
2019-06-08       00:00                    08:00                 308
2019-06-08       09:00                    09:30                 308
2019-06-08       12:15                    16:00                 308
2019-06-08       17:00                    17:30                 308
2019-06-08       18:00                    23:59                 308
```

I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to do this. My initial thought was to run 2 selects on the data to grab start and end time, then union them together into a single column with a simple code dictating which is a start/end time (1/2 respectively), creating a view from that data and pivoting it to form what I need. But I'm having trouble doing so.

The select code looks like this:

```
Create View [Room_Availability]

SELECT 

    Date
    ,start_time as 'Time'
    ,'1' as 'Time_Type'
    ,id as 'Room'

        from room_reservations

UNION

SELECT 

    Date
    ,end_time as 'Time'
    ,'1' as 'Time_Type'
    ,id as 'Room'

        from room_reservations


Results:

Date          Time      Time_Type       Room
2019-06-08    08:00     1               101
2019-06-08    12:00     1               101
2019-06-08    18:30     1               101
2019-06-08    10:00     1               201
2019-06-08    14:00     1               201
2019-06-08    08:00     1               308
2019-06-08    09:30     1               308
2019-06-08    16:00     1               308
2019-06-08    17:30     1               308
2019-06-08    09:00     2               101
2019-06-08    14:00     2               101
2019-06-08    20:00     2               101
2019-06-08    13:30     2               201
2019-06-08    15:00     2               201
2019-06-08    09:00     2               308
2019-06-08    12:15     2               308
2019-06-08    17:00     2               308
2019-06-08    18:30     2               308
```

Perhaps this was the wrong way to go about it since I can't seem to figure out how I'd pivot the data in the order I need. I'm very open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just want `lead()`: using this window function, you can retrieve the next start time of the same room. The date range from the end of the current reservation to the start of the next one on the same room defines a slot of availability:

```
select 
    date,
    room,
    end_time availability_start_time,
    lead(start_time) over(partition by room order by start_time) availability_end_time
from room_reservations
```

Comment: That does look rather promising. I hadn't heard of the Lead function before. I'll try this out!!!

Comment: While the exact SQL I ended up using didn't match yours 100%, the Lead
() function is EXACTLY what I needed to make it happen, and my solution was similar but I added a bit more to my ORDER BY and PARTITION. Thanks so much!